# Add Embebded HTML Code withut rendering on HTML Email

Tags: html, html-email

I creating HTML email but i need to send some html code without rendering (because this code for user he can copy and paste the code on there website)

i need to send this code without rendering on html email, i tried **code and pre** tags but no luck

```
<a href="###"><img src="####" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="####/><br />Watch Local Cam</a>
```

is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try html encoding it

```
&lt;a href=&quot;###&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;####&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;250&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;####/&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Watch Local Cam&lt;/a&gt;
```

<a href="###"><img src="####" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="####/><br />Watch Local Cam</a>

Comment: Wont many email clients still render the HTML anyways? Maybe I'm just doing it wrong haha

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the email as plain text, no rich text or HTML. Otherwise, save it as an HTML file and add it as an attachment.

Comment: Likely your best bet is an attachment then, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

try using Multipart/Related along with boundaries, and have the plain text part as type 'text' and the other as html where you need formatting.